# Is my approach correct in using the asp mvc controller and javascript like this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

At the moment I have a MasterPage in an ASP.NET MVC3 project with a animesearch function

```
function AnimeSearch() {
                alert(document.getElementById('anime').value);
                window.location = "Paging/AnimeBySearch?searchstring=" + (document.getElementById('anime').value);
            }
```

What I do , I type in an anime movie in an html input tag and it returns the correct values accordingly.

As one can see , is that my JavaScript function is calling my controller and then the function with the correct parameters(from the input).

However a couple of questions.

***First*** 
since this function is on my masterpage and the controller call is pretty static the following of course happens. 
When I get my result after for instance searching for "naruto" I am in the paging controller. If I want another anime movie then of course because of my static location the controller does not work anymore. 
This is my first question , what is the cleanest and proper way of handling this(no hacks please , did that , works but is not good coding )?

***Second*** 
Is my approach correct ( calling the controller and action like this from javascript )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getBaseUrl()
{
   return "@Url.Content("~/")";
}

function AnimeSearch(baseUrl) {
   alert(document.getElementById('anime').value);
   window.location = getGetBaseUrl() + "/Paging/AnimeBySearch?searchstring=" +     (document.getElementById('anime').value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this indeed does look like it would work , I'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest that you think about a rewrite of the implementation and setup a controller and view that queries the anime model. this controller would implement an action method that allowed for paging and would return a partialview that was emitted into a predefined div on your anime search view. i'm in transit on iphone at present, otherwise would leave code example.

will update when on terra firma...

Comment: My Paging Controller has the view(AnimeBySearch). This action method also allows for paging. So I'm a bit confused as to what you mean exactly, however I do get a bit of a feeling of what you mean with the partial view and it definately feels like this is the way I would like to go. If you could be more specific , it would really help me out.  Thanks btw!